# call java class from jsp

Tags: java, jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="DBConnect"%>


<%
try
{
System.out.println("\n--------------------");
System.out.println("\n loading ..");

DBConnect.connectToDb();

%>

<h3>Connection ok</h3>
<%
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

gives me following error
how to load java class in jsp

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 12 in the generated java file
The import DBConnect cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /applicationservices/fileshare/vm/TestJdbc.jsp
DBConnect cannot be resolved
13: System.out.println("\n--------------------");
14: System.out.println("\n loading ..");
15: 
16: DBConnect.connectToDb();
17: 
18: %>
19:
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a package for the application which would be something like

```
com.yourappname.data
```

then create your DBConenct class in that package or refactor it in there so that when you need to import the class you do so by using

```
import com.yourappname.data.DBConnect
```

The you can import and use the class in your jsp

```
<%@page import="com.yourappname.data.DBConnect"%>
```

On a side note, you shouldn't be doing any database acces within the jsp you should instead be doing all of your data access within a servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Add the package prefix to DBConnect:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="full.package.path.DBConnect"%>
```

Where `full.package.path` is the actual package of `DBConnect`.

Comment: @ tibtof: there is no package i directly put my DBConnect.class file in class dir

Comment: @ybc126 Don't do that, the default package (aka "directly in the class dir") is inherently broken (as shown here). Always use a package to avoid this other namespace problems. Things in the default package cannot be reference reliably from other locations.

Comment: @Philipp Reichart: now I put my class file db directory
now error is
Only a type can be imported. db.DBConnect resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 17 in the jsp 
DBConnect cannot be resolved

Comment: Can you please update the code in your question with the latest changes?

Comment: @tibtof: there are no changes.

Answer (score 0):

class should be public and methods also should be declared as public

Answer (score 0):

You page has no error. Please clean and build your project again and retest it.Putting your class in some package is good practice but without using this is no problem for test project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you see

```
DBConnect.class
```

in your

```
WEB-INF/classes
```

directory. If it's not there, the class isn't on your classpath if you are running in tomcat or similar.

Comment: @ stevedbrown: my DBConnect.class file is in WEB-INF/classes directory