# how to call file in to jsp?

Tags: java

This my JSP page.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>


    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <html>

    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

    <title>Insert title here</title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <jsp:useBean id="link" class="com.Sshexample">

    <%= link.callconst()%>

    </jsp:useBean>

    </body>

    </html>
```

i want to ask this is ma page that i musing to call .java file which is making connection with unix server.can any body tell me why i am getting this error?

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:156)

    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)

    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)

    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)

    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

i am facing this problem................?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994562/call-java-class-from-jsp). Check it out.

Comment: can you post your full stack trace of Exception?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `<jsp:useBean>` you have wrote `<%= link.callconst()%>`

```
<body>

    <jsp:useBean id="link" class="com.Sshexample">

    <%= link.callconst()%>

    </jsp:useBean>

    </body>
```

Use this

```
<body>

    <jsp:useBean id="link" class="com.Sshexample"></jsp:useBean>

     <%= link.callconst()%>
    </body>
```

Comment: pradeep i m gettin  this error:javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jscape/inet/ssh/SshListener
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:268)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause

Comment: i am actually new to java so do nt know much stack trace should be find in log files?