# how to call a .java file in jsp pages?

Tags: java, jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>

<body>

<jsp:useBean id="link" class="com.Sshexample">

<%= link.callconst()%>

</jsp:useBean>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to call a .java file from jsp. callconst is  a function which is calling the constructor of the class ? I want to call .java file when a button is clicked so I thought of forwarding one jsp to other and another jsp call to .java

```
  package com;
  import com.jscape.inet.ssh.*; 
  import com.jscape.inet.ssh.util.SshParameters;   

  public class Sshexample implements SshListener {  

  // state of SSH connection  
  private boolean connected = false;  

  /** 
   * Creates a new SshExample instance. 
   * 
   */  
  public Sshexample() {  
     Ssh ssh = null;       

     try
       {  
        // create new Ssh instance  
        SshParameters params = new SshParameters("i210","ashishga","Linux_11");  
        System.out.print("Unix server is connected ");  
        ssh = new Ssh(params);  
        // register to capture events  
        ssh.addSshListener(this);  

        System.out.println("Connecting please wait...");  
        SshScript script = new SshScript(ssh);  
        SshTask task = new SshTask("$","./call.sh","$");  

        // connect  
        script.addTask(task);  
        ssh.connect();  
        while(!script.isComplete()) {  
             Thread.sleep(100);  
            }  

        } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();              
        } finally {  
        try {  
            if(connected) {  
              ssh.disconnect();   
            }  
        } catch(Exception e) {  

         }             
      }  
  }  


  /** 
  * Captures SshConnectedEvent 
  */  
 public void connected(SshConnectedEvent ev) 
 {  
    System.out.println("Connected: " + ev.getHost());  
    connected = true;  
    System.out.println("New ashish is connected to server  "+ ev.getHost());   
}  

/** 
 * Captures SshDataReceivedEvent 
 */  
public void dataReceived(SshDataReceivedEvent ev) {  

    ev.getData();  

}  


/** 
 * Captures SshDisconnectedEvent 
 */  
public void disconnected(SshDisconnectedEvent ev) {  

    System.out.println("ashish server is Disconnecting: " + ev.getHost());  
    connected = false;  
}  

/* 
 * Main method for SshExample 
 */  
public void callconst()
{
   Sshexample t = new Sshexample();
}

}
```

ERROR:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:                                                            com/jscape/inet/ssh/SshListener
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:268)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: I guess you mean `${link.callconst()}`. Also, as stated in the other question answer, you should move the `link` code **outse** the `<jsp:useBean>` tag.

Comment: We don't know, what callconst is ;)

Comment: stop spamming by asking the same question over and over again.
Your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846849/how-to-call-file-in-to-jsp)

Comment: kkkkkk i am new here so facing little bit problem in posting q sorry for that

Comment: how can i add more code in this q can i?

Comment: actually in callconst i m calling constructor of my class let me post ma class code

Comment: you can click on the *edit* link at the bottom of your question and add more info into it, like more code or deeper description of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property **callconst** and its setter getter in class **com.Sshexample.java**
Like below code.

```
package com;

public class Sshexample {
    private String callconst = "DEAFULT DATA TO DISPLAY";

    public String getCallconst() {
        return callconst;
    }

    public void setCallconst(String callconst) {
        this.callconst = callconst;
    }


}



Access the property like below code.
 <jsp:useBean id="link" class="com.Sshexample" scope="request">          
        </jsp:useBean>

<html>  
<body>  
Data from java class :: <jsp:getProperty name="link" property="callconst"/>  

</body></html>
```

Another way to access your java class is with the help of scriptlet let me write the code

```
<%@ page import="com.Sshexample" %>

    <%

Sshexample obj = new Sshexample();

String dataTodisplay = obj .getCallconst();


%>


<html>  
    <body>  
    Data from java class :: <%=dataTodisplay%>

    </body></html>
```

Comment: real i musing this code in ma java class

Comment: so are you getting any exception or there is no display

Comment: actually i m new to industry and do nt have much practical knowledge just theortical overview so can you elaborate setter getter?

Comment: modified answer as per your requirement

Comment: hi real thanks for the answers but actually i want to call constructor of my class?

Comment: public void callconst()
   {
    Sshexample t = new Sshexample();
   }   thats why i m calling callconst

Comment: plz help me i want to post my class code here but unable to do how can i post code of class?

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jscape/inet/ssh/SshListener
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:268)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Comment: i am getting this error

Comment: Ok i guess there is problem in your JSP edit your question and paste your entire jsp content

Comment: I have modified my answer to meet your requirements.

Comment: Modify your jsp according to above answer and let me know if you are still getting exception

Comment: hi real i hve edit above my class code which i want to run on a button click.

Comment: which will run unix script can u post  some code which on a click of a button call this above java code.

Comment: add jar file containig class com/jscape/inet/ssh/SshListener in WEB-INF lib folder and redeploy your application tomcat

Comment: i m using eclipse and i ahve add jar files in the project folder but to add in to web inf libs ...do nt know

Comment: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Comment: how to add jars in  web inf lib folder i have added in project folder by right clicking the project and goes to build path and add external jars.

Comment: copy that jar file in from project to WEB-INF lib folder manually.

Comment: create a folder lib in WEb-INF directory add paste jar file inside the lib folder

Comment: hi real thanks now ma that problem is removed by adding manuall jar files but now i m get

Comment: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot find any information on property 'callconst' in a bean of type 'com.Sshexample'

Comment: thanks real for u r help its working fine thanks a lot real :)

Comment: real now i want to call my this jsp page into another jsp page on click button <body>
<form method="post" action="Button2.jsp">
<button>clickme!</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: i want on click button this jsp should call another jsp button2.jsp

Comment: Have you got your answers